# How to read a stack.peek in order to put it in an if statement C#

Tags: c#, stack, peek

I am trying to create a menu system and i am storing the menus in stacks once they have already been visited. Im trying to use Stack.Peek() to basically say: if menuName = menuStack.Peek, then continue.

menus have a drawRectangle, sprite, and Menuname enumeration associated with them, and all menus are child classes of the Menu class.

```
    public static void GoToMenu(MenuName menuName)
    {
        Stack<Menu> menuStack = new Stack<Menu>();
        Stack<Menu> tempStack = new Stack<Menu>();
        if(menuStack.Peek() = MainMenu){

        }
    }
```

More or less, if menuStack.Peek returns a mainMenu object. How do i check that?

i just really dont know how to read menuStack.Peek(). I dont know how to apply it to an if statement to check if it equals a mainmenu object, a pausemenu object or whatever.

Comment: Okay, so what's your question/problem?

Comment: if(menuStack.Peek() = MainMenu) doesnt compile, i need to be able to use stack functions peek pop and push to iterate through these lists and i have never done a stack using an object.

Comment: Try `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: i have tried that, doesnt work

Comment: Try telling us the actual error then.

Comment: There is no error, i just really dont know how to read menuStack.Peek(). I dont know how to apply it to an if statement to check if it equals a mainmenu object, a pausemenu object or whatever.

Comment: if you want to check if an object is of a particular class, you can use `is`. Eg. `(menuStack.Peek() is MainMenu)`

Comment: thats close to what i needed, but it got me where i needed to go. i posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void GoToMenu(MenuName menuName)
    {
        Stack<Menu> menuStack = new Stack<Menu>();
        Stack<Menu> tempStack = new Stack<Menu>();
        if(menuStack.Peek().Name == menuName){
            menuStack.Pop();
        }
    }
```

that is what i needed

Comment: This is how you determine if an object is an instance of a type.  That is just one of an infinite number of possible ways you could compare objects, and it can be done inside or outside of an `if` statement.

Comment: so another quick question, using that i am able to check if the top object on my stack is of type MainMenu, but how would i make it check all menus but if they had the field MenuName = mainMenu? Remember i have mainmenu, difficultymenu, pausemenu all child classes of Menu

Comment: nvm, figured it out =)